# Zipping all subfolders in a folder - Python

Tags: python, shutil

I made a script to zip all subfolders in a specific folder (I want one zip per subfolder) but it seems that shutil doesn't recognize " - " (space/hyphen/space) :

```
import os
import shutil
path = r"C:\Users\MME106\OneDrive - Compagny\Bureau\Test_py_pdf\Folders"
for folder in os.listdir(path):
    shutil.make_archive(folder, 'zip', path)
```

it does the job but save the zip files directly in "C:\Users\MME106"

I think there is a problem coming from the path...

I tried also :

`path = '"C:\Users\MME106\OneDrive - Company\Bureau\Test_py_pdf\Folders"'` => same as with r

`path = @"C:\Users\MME106\OneDrive - Company\Bureau\Test_py_pdf\Folders"` => doesn't work

Comment: `os.listdir` only returns names, not full paths. This causes `shutil.make_archive` to create files inside the current working directory, which seems to be your home folder.

Comment: (which is to say, you'd have the same problem with no spaces or dashes involved)

Comment: Your third param `path` also stays the same, meaning you create the same ZIP for all folder names. Create new paths using `os.join` for both the fodler to be zippedand resuling ZIP file.

Comment: Here is my final code 
`import os
import shutil
path = r"C:\Users\MME106\OneDrive - Company\Bureau\Test_py_pdf\Folders"
for folder in os.listdir(path):
    folder2zip = path + '\\' + folder 
     shutil.make_archive(folder2zip, 'zip', folder2zip)`